# How to label only some places instead of all?

Tags: qgis, labeling, places

How do I turn of some place names, or rather turn on some places names but not the rest.  How do I turn of or hide that?

<del>I also get a red cross under the place names which I don't like to see.
How do I turn of or hide that?</del>

The place names is in a line layer (using labelling), and there are also many numbers I  don't need to see.  Some of them are Height above mean sea level (AMSL), but not all.

QGIS Lisboa versjon 1.8.0

[image]

Comment: The red crosses are probably because the layer is being edited (pencil symbol in overview). Just switch off editing for that layer. Can you post a screen shot of your attribute table?

Comment: Install QGIS 2.0.1 as Andre Joost mentions - you can run both 1.8 and 2.0.1 on the same computer.

Comment: Are the new version easyer to use? (Or maybe more simular to ArcGis?)

Comment: They offer new features the developers have implemented recently.

Answer (score 4):

Andre provides a very practical solution.  However, another option, instead of creating the extra column and editing it, you can use an expression in the labels section to allow only certain values to be used.  Click the 'curly E' next to the 'Label this layer with' button.  The Operators and Conditionals will help you build more sophisticated expressions.  Have a look [here](http://anitagraser.com/2011/12/30/conditional-labels-in-qgis/) for more discussion on expression-based labeling.

Comment: This will not work for QGIS Lisboa, and might get confusing if you want a bunch of different objects labeled.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a copy of the labeling column using field calculator, then delete the values in that column (not the complete row) for those elements you do not want to be labelled.

If you switch to QGIS 2.0.1, you can use a lot more functions to select if and how elements are labelled.

Answer (score 2):

Exampel of a simple expression based label

```
CASE WHEN "eRegion" = 'Region' THEN 
    "eRegion" 
ELSE 
   "noRegionname" 
END
```

The above states that if column eRegion = the text Region then use eRegion as label. If not the use the column noRegionname as label.